# What is a free or inexpensive PHP script for family trees?

Tags: php, web

I am looking for a reasonable costing PHP script for my website. I am not paying $40 plus to myheritage or ancestry.

I prefer a one time cost or a small yearly cost.

A tree view us a must and it would be nice if it supported photos.

Comment: Maybe [phpGedView](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpgedview/) fits? Wasn't updated for a while, but other than the name suggests doesn't only "view", but even supports collaborative editing. Comes free of costs. [GeneoTree](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geneotree/) might be an alternative with a more recent update and similar looks.

Answer (score 0):

[Family Tree JS](https://balkan.app/FamilyTreeJS) has all functionalities you need and it is one-time cost

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at [Webtrees](https://github.com/fisharebest/webtrees).

- It is opensource.
- It supports trees, photos and other documents.

You can see a demo [here](https://dev.webtrees.net/demo-dev/tree/demo/pedigree-right-4/i1).

edit:
I have subsequently been using webtrees - highly recommended.
The [Web Descendants Chart](https://github.com/magicsunday/webtrees-descendants-chart) module gives you the tree view.